# Nicolas Cage film where there are multiples of himself appearing from him

Tags: story-identification

I saw the part of this film the other night as I was waiting for my PVR to finish recording *Iron Man 3* so I can only describe a small part of the film.

In the film, Nicolas Cage (whose voice and general appearance I remember from *Ghost Rider* and *National Treasure*) was in what seemed to be a warehouse. He is leading a group who I think are law enforcement, and as he walks forward there seems to be multiples of himself separating from his body.

The multiples seem to go in every direction. Some get ambushed and killed but then he would appear again in that same area as if he reversed time but now with the foreknowledge of how not to be killed there.

There was also a scene in the warehouse where he starts getting shot at (this time it doesn't seem to be a multiple). As he moves forward he moves around kinda like the Agents in *The Matrix* in avoiding the bullets but you see that in some of the after images he gets shot.

That's about as much as I know. It was almost midnight by the time the PVR stopped recording and I had work in the morning.

Comment: +1 because Nicolas Cage is the greatest actor of our age.

Comment: I'd like to take his face... off...

Comment: It's "Next" - a pretty decent flick. The multiple versions thing was a visualization of alternate timelines that didn't pan out. He could see the future, so each multiple version represented his vision of a timeline where he went left instead of right, up instead of down, etc.

Comment: The end of "Next" was really disappointing though. It's just sort of...what's next?

Comment: “whose voice and general appearance I remember from *Ghost Rider* and *National Treasure*” — you have not seen good Nicholas Cage films. Might I recommend *Con Air*.

Comment: @PaulDWaite you seem to be implying that National Treasure was *not* a good Nick Cage film?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The movie you're looking for is **[Next](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0435705/)**:

- Stars [Nicholas Cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Cage)
- He sees into the very near future
- You can see him doing the 'split' thing in the IMDb trailer
- He memorises the events as he sees them and is able to respond when he *actually* goes through it
- Features the warehouse scene you referred to
- > When he's near Liz (Jessica Biel's character), he can see much further into the future.
- > He uses his 'ability' to help the FBI prevent a terrorist attack

Comment: Movie description on IMDB: _A Las Vegas magician who can see into the future_... How did this not win an Oscar??

Comment: It's definitely *Next*.  I liked it, except that as I recall the credits started at what should have been about 3/4 of the way through.

Comment: @cjm I know what you mean. The ending throws people off, because it essentially says that 3/4 of the movie never happened. MIND = BLOWN.

Comment: The storyline sounds similar to a book I read called _Blink_ by Ted Dekker published in 2002. A man can see a short way into the future and a couple of different possibilities if he does different things. As the book progresses his power increases and he is able to see more choices and further into the future. From the blurb he can _see multiple potential futures_. I wonder if the movie _Next_ was based on this book?

Comment: @CJDennis According to the Wikipedia article in [Layna's Answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/86881/21267) it was based on *The Golden Man* by Philip K. Dick.

Comment: Now I wonder if Dekker based his book on Dick's!

Comment: @Mooz, *Next* is *very, very loosely* based on *The Golden Man*.  They both have a character who can see into the near future.  That's pretty much where the similarity ends; *The Golden Man* has a very different plot.

Answer (score 15):

It should be *[Next](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_%282007_film%29)* from 2007. All the elements you describe fully match :). The multiples where scouting the warehouse, and he dodged the bullets because he could see where they would go.

Comment: :-P He dodged the bullets because he played through a whole bunch of paths until he found one that didn't get him killed. I remember thinking that this has to leave some scars on his mind, seeing himself killed over and over again.